# Wsdl adress location is showing host name rather than localhost

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, soap, wsdl

I have created wsdls as mentioned in **2.6 Code first web service implementation** section  in the following link
http://www.wideskills.com/jax-ws/create-web-service-using-jax-ws.Created ears and deployed them on tomcat server. In that url,I have wsdls for several web services.The problem is: I am getting the address as  **appSever:8080/services/mul?wsdl** and for other web service, I am getting **localhost:8080/services/sum?wsd**l.I need for all the wsdls to have **localhost:8080**. What may be the cause for this issue.This problem is intermittent. I have following entries in the etc/hosts file in windows

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
# ::1    localhost
127.0.0.1 appServer
```

I don't want to remove appServer in hosts file because am using it in other location.Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with CXF below 3.XXXX
Solution for this is explained here in

http://srikanthhugar.blogspot.com/2014/02/cxf-cxfservlet-disable-address-updates.html